# Do we say "strip me by eyes" or "strip me by the eyes"?

Tags: definite-article

Do we say:

> You strip me by eyes

or

> You strip me by the eyes

?
The sense I intend to get is something like, a person undressing someone else just by looking at him.

Comment: 'You strip (or better, undress) me with your eyes' sounds more natural than either of those sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is [undress sb. with one's eyes.](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/undress_with_one%27s_eyes)

As often happens in idioms, we wouldn't ever say "strip" here even though it's a synonym for "undress".

So, the expression you're looking for is

```
You undress me with your eyes.
```